# Is there any valid situation where you would use O_APPEND and O_RDONLY?

Tags: c, io, system-calls

On unix like systems, attempting to call the `write` function on a file descriptor can sometimes result in the error:

```
[EBADF]  fildes is not a valid file descriptor open for writing.
```

This is typically when the file descriptor has been opened with `open` and a combination of flags that does not include `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`.

(see man 2 open, man 2 write for more info)

So, the question:

In what circumstances is it *ever valid* to call `open` with any of `O_APPEND`, `O_TRUNC`, `O_CREAT`, without also passing one of the write flags?

This is specifically because of a recent issue in which I encountered that passing only the `O_APPEND` flag would successfully open the file, but calling `write` on the fd would result in `EBADF` because I failed to pass something other than `O_RDONLY` along to the `open` call.

I would expect the `open` should fail with some error if an invalid combination of flags (eg. `O_APPEND` without any write flag), but it does not. Is there some reason for this, or is it just an artifact of the historical posix standard?

Is there, ever, a situation where `O_APPEND` + `O_RDONLY` is a valid combination?

Comment: Because it doesn't. It doesn't matter why that original decision was made, and speculating on it here is irrelevant and simply discussion. What difference could it possibly make now why the design decision was made? The fact is that it doesn't fail during compilation, and therefore you need to make sure you specify a valid combination of flags.

Comment: @KenWhite: s/valid/useful/

Comment: @KenWhite Its actually quite relevant, specifically see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23626 <--- Should we keep this arbitrary chosen behaviour for the high level abstraction in rust or not? I'm certainly not just idly looking for a chat. If there's no meaningful purpose to allowing this, the high level abstraction in rust should not allow it.

Comment: Your question asks *why the standard C library `open()` does not validate the combination of flags it receives*. There's no mention of design considerations in rust; nor is rust in the tags (or the text). As it's (well) written, it's phrased as a discussion of why a historical decision was made at the time.

Comment: @KenWhite Honestly, I'm not sure what you want from me. I'm sorry if my question does not meet the rigorous standard of SO questions in how it is phrased. However, I maintain this is a simple yes / no answer that I just need a categorical answer to: Is there, ever, a situation where O_APPEND + O_RDONLY is a valid combination? I'm happy to just ignore the whole historical side of this, it's really not relevant, except in that perhaps it may inform some situation in which the above is valid.

Comment: @Doug: I see your point, and it's true that, judging just by the title, this is an example of a *very good* question. Its practical applications may be are rather limited, but noone here cares about that. Unfortunately the text ends with another, very different question -- one that as Ken mentioned is rather pointless since it cannot be answered (and an answer would not be useful at all even if achieved). I think that if you edited the text to be focused on the good side of the coin this would be a question hard for even the biggest stickler to find fault with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "valid".

AFAICT, POSIX doesn't specifically mention this combination of flags. but it does say:

> Applications shall specify exactly one of the first five values (file
>   access modes) below in the value of oflag:
>
> - O_EXEC
> - O_RDONLY
> - O_RDWR
> - O_SEARCH
> - O_WRONLY

and then

> Not all combinations of flags make sense. For example, using O_SEARCH | O_CREAT will successfully open a pre-existing directory for searching, but if there is no existing file by that name, then it is unspecified whether a regular file will be created.

I would conclude that a lone O_APPEND would fall under "unspecified" behavior according to POSIX (i.e., don't do that).

See here for more info: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: For reference, this is in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any situations where passing `O_APPEND` along with `O_RDONLY` would have a different effect than just passing `O_RDONLY`. SUSv4 [seems to imply](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) that it should be allowed at least.

For `O_TRUNC`, SUSv4 doesn't specify the behavior when passing `O_RDONLY`:

> The result of using `O_TRUNC` without either `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY` is undefined.

[fcntl()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) can change status flags on the descriptor after it's created, and so might seem like a way in which e.g. `O_APPEND` could matter when opening a file `O_RDONLY`. However,

> Bits corresponding to the file access mode and the file creation flags, as defined in *<fcntl.h>*, that are set in arg shall be ignored. If any bits in arg other than those mentioned here are changed by the application, the result is unspecified

On Linux, `fcntl(2)` can change the `O_APPEND`, `O_ASYNC`, `O_DIRECT`,  `O_NOATIME`, and `O_NONBLOCK` flags, but none of those would make a difference re. this discussion.

Slightly contrived, but I guess passing `O_RDONLY | O_APPEND` might affect what flags you get back when you do `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, ...)`. I haven't actually confirmed that though.

As for why things were designed this way, I don't know.